# If an article is part of the name, do you still contract it with à or de ?

Tags: grammaire, articles, noms-propres, contractions

If one were, for example, near the *Les Gobelins* stop on the Paris metro, would they say "Je suis à Les Gobelins," or "Je suis aux Gobelins" ?

Same thing, another example sentence: "Je me souviens de Les Gobelins" or "Je me souviens des Gobelins" ?

Comment: « Je suis à Gobelins » est la façon la plus courante de le dire.  Sans l'article défini. Mais il n'en va pas ainsi de toutes les stations de Métro. Je pense que c'est parce que c'est un nom propre dès  le départ. « Je suis / je descends aux Halles.  » parce que Halles, bien que nom propre ici  (nom du quartier), était au départ un nom commun (la construction qui servit de halles). En passant en revue les noms de stations de métro (parisiennes) j'ai l'impression que c'est du cas par cas influencé par des raisons autant historiques que linguistiques.

Comment: Très interéssant. Un phénomène qui n'existe pas en anglais.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use two sentence for this

> Je suis à l'arrêt *Les Gobelins*

In this first sentence you specify what is "Les Gobelins". In this case it is a stop (*arrêt*). Use this sentence for formal conversation.

> Je suis aux *Gobelins*

You can use this in a familiar conversation. The person you are talking with should know that *Les Gobelins* is a stop on the metro. If he does not know it, it may sounds weird for him and will not understand.

Comment: So it is grammatically correct to form the contraction, but the usage can be questionable depending on the context and need for clarity, and thus should be sometimes avoided, when needed. But *Je suis à Les Gobelins* is simply grammatically wrong. Is that right?

Comment: I am not good enough in grammar to pretend that it is correct. But as native french speaker those 2 sentences are understable and correct. I will use the second one when speaking with a friend that knows this stop

Comment: « Je suis à Gobelins » (sans le mot « arrêt » et sans l'article défini) est la façon la plus courante de le dire. On ne dirait jamais « Je suis aux Gobelins ».

Comment: Autant pour moi, je pense que cela dépend aussi de la région/pays ainsi que du nom de l'arrêt

Comment: Je pense aussi que ce sont des habitudes locales et qu'il est difficile de tirer une règle. Ce qui est sûr, comme tu dis, on ne dirait jamais « à Les Gobelins. » Et je pense qu'on ne dirait pas « aux Gobelins » pour parler de la station de métro à cause de la confusion avec le bâtiment de (la manufacture) des Gobelins et que les deux sont proches.

Comment: Effectivement, n'étant pas parisiens (ni même Francais) je ne savais pas qu'il y avait confusion possible avec un batiment